# Can't export model from Custom Vision

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, microsoft-custom-vision

I can export the first iteration, but when I try exporting the second one, it only shows the message "Failed".

Answer (score 0):

We had issues in West Europe region yesterday. The issue should be fixed now. Please give a try again.

Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 0):

Note, the VisionAI camera will only work with the 'General Compact' format. So an export w/ other settings can cause the 'failed ' error.